# how to display an inserted query data without refreshing using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

What i have right now is a form and a container that displays the submitted data and it is submitting without refresh using ajax request, the form and the container that displays the data are on the same page.

I have tried getting the input value inside the form using `$("id").val();` and display it using `$('#display').html();`

But I have many input fields inside the form and I dont wanna copy paste all of the input values inside the jquery because it seems like it's unprofessional and dirty and not efficient.

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_rec").click(function(e){
        var me = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( me.data('requestRunning') ) {
            return;
        }
        var inputs = $("#u_rec_form").serialize();

        me.data('requestRunning', true);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: inputs,
            success: function(data){
                    alert(data);

                },
                 complete: function() {
                    me.data('requestRunning', false);
                }
            });

        return false;

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="u_rec_form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-7">
            <label for="code">Patient's Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="cust_username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-7 ">
            <label for="code">Patient's Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="cust_password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-normal" />
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-7">
            <label for="code">Patient's First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="cust_fname" placeholder="First name" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-7">
            <label for="code">Patient's Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="cust_lname" placeholder="Last name" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-7">
            <label for="code">Patient's Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" name="cust_age" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
            <button type="submit" id="add_rec" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Is there any other way to do it?

I have these inputs

```
<label for="code">First Name: <span id="view_<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['cust_fname']?></span></label><br><br>
<label for="code">Last Name: <span id="view_<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['cust_lname']?></span></label><br><br>
<label for="code">Age: <span id="view_<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['cust_age']?></span></label>
```

I tried using this
      $('input').each(function(){
            var inputVal = $(this).val();
            $('span').append(inputVal);
        });
I will display all the input values in each label and thats not what i want

Comment: Definitely something missing in the problem description. Not clear what the exact problem is. You mentioned one container ... then mention numerous inputs and repeating code....to do what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

use the ".append()" method instead of .html().

UPDATE:

If you want to get all the data of the input and then display it you can iterate to each input field and then display it. Add a class first to the input elements so it will be easily editable.

```
$('.input-class').each(function(){
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      $('#display').append(inputVal);
})
```